# Brand new CentOS 7 install "connection timed out"

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

ok, here's the crux of the issue:

I have a brand new CentOS 7 install running out of VirtualBox.  I can access everything on that box externally via domain name... except HTTP. I get a connection timeout error even when trying to load the site via 192.168.1.100.

Here's the background:

I've been running a local server out of a VirtualBox install of Debian for a couple years, but it was 1) getting very out of date and 2) had a bunch of weird problems due to improper host shutdowns (yay windows update thinking it's the most important thing ever).  So, I decided it was time to start fresh, and CentOS seems to be the goto for simple CLI servers.  After some fun with networking, I have 2 VMs running.  Originally, the server was run off of the box at .100, and the new box .101.  Rather than mess with port forwarding, I swapped static IPs.

At first everything looked great - ping, SSH, FTP all connect fine even via external domain name - but all I can get from HTTP is a 15s timeout, even when hitting the local net IP directly.  I can still access the site from the old box via 192.168.1.101 or editing my hosts file.

Versions are all brand new installs, so they are what's in Yum: apache 2.4.6, php 5.5.16.  Output from httpd -S:

```
07:41:33 eshields@localhost {~/env}(master)[77]$ httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/000-personal-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/000-personal-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/000-personal-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost gallery.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/001-personal-gallery.conf:1)
                 alias grabme.coldcandor.com
         port 80 namevhost gallery.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/001-personal-gallery.conf:1)
                 alias grabme.coldcandor.com
         port 80 namevhost old.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/002-personal-old.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost old.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/002-personal-old.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost freedomschoice.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/003-personal-freedomschoice.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost freedomschoice.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/003-personal-freedomschoice.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost beta.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/004-personal-beta.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost beta.coldcandor.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/004-personal-beta.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/etc/httpd/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48 not_used
Group: name="apache" id=48 not_used
```

/var/log/messages and /var/log/httpd/error_log are clean.  /var/log/httpd/access_log has no entries aside from the apache startup internal dummy connection.

Edit:  Even swapping back to a fresh install of apache isn't working.  So, it's got to be something at a higher (lower?) level, but I can't think what could cause HTTP to fail even for the test page, when all the other connection types work...

Any ideas what's going on?  Connection timeout sounds like a domain/router type problem, but everything is great there.  And it's not a config syntax or vhost problem, because there are 0 errors, and even the default won't load.

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue!  There was a preinstalled firewall on the VM called iptables that was blocking all port 80 connections.

I just knew it was some simple thing.  I installed the "minimalist" CentOS7 server, which didn't even come with things like vim or tree, much less apache, so I never expected it would have a preinstalled and configured firewall...